# Resharper 6.1 VS 2010 - Unable to edit read-only files. (In memory)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Here's my problem:  I believe I accidentally checked "Do not ask this question again" on a prompt that reads "This file is read only, do you want to edit this in memory". Now when I attempt to edit any read-only file I can insert or replace code but I can't delete it.  As minor as this problem seems it's becoming a signification annoyance.

Disabling Resharper eliminates the problem.  Does anyone have any idea where the setting is to re-enable in-memory edits of read-only files (or if it exists)?  I've tried the registry edit: AllowUncontrolledInMemoryEditing from 1 to 0 with no luck.

Here's my setup:

- Windows 7
- VS 2010 SP1
- Resharper 6.1

Thanks!

Comment: Did you come up with any solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't.  The best solution I found was to disable ReSharper.  Right now I've got ReSharper enabled and I'm just living with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's could be a Resharper option but I'm not aware it has one built in.

Visual studio has one though -> Tools -> Options ->Documents and the fourth option down is "Allow editing of read-only files"

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is most definitely a ReSharper issue.  The setting you refer to is enabled (i.e. the checkbox is checked).  The only way I get around this problem is by disabling ReSharper.  I appreciate the input!